# Is it possible to send email without JDK?

Tags: java, email-client

I'm aware about JDK implementation of email sending (via SMTP), but I'm looking for something custom, which would **not** use JDK. Such libraries exist? I need it for better testability of my app.

Comment: Not JDK but Java mail? https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking: you want to execute Java code without using JDK classes? That's impossible. Anyway, that question is off-topic.

Comment: If you mean sending email without using the implementation within the JDK (but still using Java), you can send emails with command line programs too. Use `Process` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Comment: I don't get your reasoning, why would that improve testability?

Comment: [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) is a very simple (as the name said) protocol. You can implement it with sockets in a few lines. But to send mail out to the internet you really needs an infrastructure (domain, secure laysers, etc) to not get blocked.

Comment: it's difficult (next to impossible) to mock Java Mail :(

Comment: So you could write your own mail service with a simple, easily mockable interface that delegates to Java Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use [apache commons exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) to run something like:

```
echo "hello" | mail -s subject user@example.com
```

Comment: Is it true that in this way mailing to remote domains is not supported?

Comment: Hmm. Why? This uses the mail command of O/S. I guess it could send anywhere.

Comment: But how when i don't have any valid mail server installed in my own domain (for example my pc)? mail transactions needs to be done through valid servers, i mean for example `smtp.google.com`, there is some steps that must pass and then your mail may route by that server. for example authentication and so on.

Comment: @muradin You don't need an relay server. Mails can be sent to any mail server from your local machine. But in many cases - thanks to spam - the mail server will not accept your mail.

Comment: @muradin : if you can send mail from a machine with a mail client (winmail, thuderbird,...), as the mail client uses SMTP, you can send mail with direct SMTP. You simply have to use same server and same authentication if appropriate.

Comment: @Hannes: And if it does not count as spam in the remote server what is the `from` tag? I mean if the `from` could set manually (for example myname@mypcname) isn't this a security hazard?

Comment: @muradin At the time when email was invented nobody would ever do this. What's the sense of a letter if nobody can respond to it they thought. Also the mail server where scarse at the time and not everyone had access to it. Nowadays the `from` is just a field to be filled with a syntactical correct mail address. That doesn't mean it exists or belongs to the sender.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it for better testability of my app.

Use the mail functionality from java-mail. That's how it's done.

For you testcases use a Dummy-Implementation using a singleton, or just skip the part, where you `transfer` the mail.

Testability has nothing to do with it.

If I use mail functionality in projects, I normally send the mails to one account in the test environment, overriding the original target. But after that, e.i. in integration and qa environments mails are sent allready to the testers.

In automated test either don't test it at all, or mock the call. In any way validation should be done prior to sending a mail.